# How do I prevent execution of injected JavaScript after its initial execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add javascript to my page after ajax call as I have newly created elements from the ajax response and I want them to listen to the javascript. Eveything works okay.

However,for some reason, I want to block that JavaScript functionality at some later point in time.

I have tried removing the script tag from the html using Javascript but it's not being effective. I have even tried using libraries such as
 [YETT](https://github.com/snipsco/yett) but still i am not able to block the script I intend to block.

Javascript code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(()=>{
        //when the page first  loads I append the script (NOTE:I have this inside an ajax call as I am 
         appending html elements from the ajax call response

      const scriptsrc =  document.createElement('script')
       scriptsrc.setAttribute('type','text/javascript')
      scriptsrc.setAttribute('src','./assests/scripts/script.js_r='+Math.random()+Math.pow(10,10).toString(2))
       scriptsrc.setAttribute('data-name','myscript')
       $('head').append(scriptsrc)

    //i do some other stuff here
    //I want to block the script that i previously added (./assests/scripts/script.js) below here

   })
</script>
```

Comment: Once a script is added, you can't un-add it. It's already run and any effects it has - such as global variables or event listeners - are set.

Comment: meaning i need to reload the entire page again?

Comment: If you're *very careful*, you could probably have some kind of "mode" variable, and add a check to every function in your added script to only run if that "mode" is correct.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you assist with an example?

Comment: You cannot stop a library from executing once it has been run. The only thing you can do is to undo its effect, most easily if the library itself does provide an API to do that.